# Automated processing form data framework for WinApi or MFC

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

Please, is there some some framework to automate processing of data from WinApi controls in forms (like filling forms, saving form data)?
I was googling, but without any luck.

Comment: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: This is for automating task like clicking on buttons or filling inputs as user do. I need some framework, that I can set up in dialog constructor and this framework do the hard work like filling inputs, saving data, validating forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Mercury WinRunner** (now HP) or any other UI automation tools.

Comment: This is misunderstanding, I don't need UI automation tools, I need something, that I set up in code of dialog and this thing do the hard work form me - fill form fields, validate and save data on submitting the form.

Comment: The MFC framework comes with built in DDX/DDV exchange technology that has all the features that you need including basic validation.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/windows/desktop/57weza95(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I see, that in MFC is validation and data exchange, but it only set some properties in class.
I imagined that I set in constructor data source and validation method and everything else will be done by itself.